# A topic up with which I'm fed

Tags: prepositions, grammar-myths

The correct grammar for *I'm fed up with this topic.* would be *This is a topic up with which I'm fed.* which sound ridiculous. Is there a grammatical rule or guideline that states the first quote is acceptable?

Comment: with which i'm fed up ?

Comment: @random That still ends with a preposition.

Comment: The "rule" about not ending sentence with a preposition is a complete nonsense up with which I will not put.

Comment: @Jay ah ? I've never heard about this rule, that must be the reason :)

Comment: Can you tell us where you found a grammatical rule that suggests that the ridiculous version is correct? That rule is surely mistaken, but it might help someone write an answer if they knew more about what led you to the first sentence of your question.

Comment: @JimM It's a paraphrase of alleged reaction of Churchill to a clumsy attempt to "fix" his wording.

Comment: @Jay - _fed up_ is a phrasal verb – the way I parse it, I'm not sure that counts as a preposition.

Comment: See also [Churchill's quote: “This is just the sort of nonsense up with which I will not put.”](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2793/churchills-quote-this-is-just-the-sort-of-nonsense-up-with-which-i-will-not-p)

Comment: @BenKovitz By the rule (that most of us here disparage) that you cannot end a sentence with a preposition, students are routinely told that rather than say, for example, "This is something I'm not happy with", you should say, "This is something with which I am not happy." So by the same reasoning, instead of "This is a topic I'm fed up with", you should say, "This is a topic up with which I am fed." I'd say that's absurd, and the only reason for saying such a monstrosity is to abide by a silly rule.

Comment: @jr Well, "up" is a preposition. By a dogmatic and uncompromising application of the rule, you can't use it to end a sentence. Perhaps a case could be made for the no-ending-preposition rule in general but saying that phrases like "fed up" are exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is another example that demonstrates why the "never use a preposition to end a sentence with" rule is silly. Ignore this rule.

Comment: Do not ignore this rule.  If you can't end the sentence properly, that tells you you've improperly structured it from the outset.

Comment: Nonsense. Ending a sentence with a preposition does **not** mean that it is structured improperly, or ended improperly. The "rule" is nothing of the sort.

Comment: As a matter of fact it does.  By definition, you cannot change up a prepositional phrase's word order.  It's preposition-noun.  If you end the sentence with a preposition, then you've inverted the prepositional phrase's word order - noun-preposition.  It's a rule.  We're done.

Comment: @user9570789 As Winston Churchill famously said, "That is a rule up with which I shall not put." Who said it's a rule? Why should we obey it? I can easily think of many examples where it makes a sentence awkward and difficult to understand. Just because somebody wrote it on a piece of paper somewhere doesn't make it a good rule.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you're first sentence was grammatically correct.  *I'm fed up with this topic.*

It did not end in a preposition, and further more, up isn't a preposition in this sentence.  Prepositions don't stand alone, they make up prepositional phrases.  Prepositional phrases begin with a preposition and end with a noun.

That's why ending a sentence with a preposition is wrong, and it sounds wrong, because you're ending the prepositional phrase with a preposition, instead of with its noun.

Thus, "fed up" is a state of being.  That means it's actually the verb in your sentence.  *I'm verb with this noun!*

If "up" were a preposition, then "fed" would have to be the noun, and it should always appear "up fed".  *I'm up fed with this topic.*  Clearly, that's the ridiculous thing here, not the rule.

Thus, the rule doesn't apply in this case and never did.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

"fed up with" is an idiom and stands together, however you chose to parse it. "Fed up" may be regarded as a derived verb, althoguh not in the sentence

> I'm afraid George is simply fed up.

In either case "fed up" does indicate a state of being.

> This is a topic up with which I'm fed.

does not work, because it breaks the idiom. It may be understood, as a humorous reworking of the idiom, but if so it works precisely because it is, in the normal way of things, wrong, or at least abnormal.